# c# How to button.Visible = true when string exists?

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to make visible a button, but only when a string exists. This is the way I thought, but I'm not seeing any change to my UI. Furthermore, the loop doesn't exit, despite only returning a single result.

```
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnStr))
{
    con.Open();
               
                
    string sqlCON = "SELECT CV_EXIST FROM DATA_NEURON.DM_CV WHERE DWH_CUSTOMER_KEY = '123321'";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlCON con);
                
    using (MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())   
        {
            var check = rdr.GetString(0);
                        
            if (check == "YES")
            {
                button_cv.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                button_cv.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you and sorry for my english.

Comment: Please define "it doesn't work". But clearly, in your case, if there are many results when executing the reader and iterating over it, `check` will change every iteration. So you need to break your loop when your condition is met.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "it doesn´t work" means i don´t get any response. On the other hand, there is no many results, just one which is, in this case, "YES".  how could I break the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Please note, that in your current implementation `button_cv` doesn't change its state when cursor is *empty* and `while` loop is not entered; another
possible issues are (trailing) *spaces* (`"YES   "`) and *case* (`"yes"`, `"Yes"` etc.). If it is "doesn't work" then I suggest something like this:

```
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnStr)) {
  con.Open();

  //DONE: please, keep SQL readable
  //DONE: parametrize the query or have a good reason not to do it  
  string sqlCON = 
     @"SELECT CV_EXIST  
         FROM DATA_NEURON.DM_CV 
        WHERE DWH_CUSTOMER_KEY = @Key";

  //DONE: do not forget to dispose IDisposable - using
  using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlCON, con)) {
    //TODO: you may want to change MySqlDbType type, to, say, MySqlDbType.Int32
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Key", "123321", MySqlDbType.VarString);

    // You don't need the entire cursor here, just the 1st record if it exists
    button_cv.Visible = "YES".Equals(
      cmd.ExecuteScalar()?.ToString()?.Trim(), 
      StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
  }
}
```

Here I've assumed that empty cursor means `NO`; if it is `YES` then all you need is to change a single line by adding  `?? "YES"`:

```
  cmd.ExecuteScalar()?.ToString()?.Trim() ?? "YES",
```

Answer (score 0):

this code has syntax error :

---

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlCON con);
```

---

best way is write a method for recognize button visibility and use its :

---

```
public static bool GetButtonVisibility()
{
    using (var con = new MySqlConnection("connection string"))
    {
        con.Open();
        var query = "SELECT CV_EXIST FROM DATA_NEURON.DM_CV WHERE DWH_CUSTOMER_KEY = '123321'";
        var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            return rdr.Read() && rdr.GetString(0) == "YES";
    }
}
```

---

```
button_cv.Visible = GetButtonVisibility();
```